# Stored Procedure Output Value Not Updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Everyone.

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 that has the purpose of giving the of the total number of sales recommendations [@Recommendation in Recommendations table] in my table that contain this string: '____Document DOB in sales record' past any given date. I want to put this result into a temporary table as well.

**Helpful Table Info:**

- Reference Table where I am grabbing the data: **Recommendations**
- The relevant fields in the Recommendations table are @Recommendation, and @SalesProcessTime
- The @Recommendation field is a VARCHAR(255), and @SalesProcessTime is a DATETIME

**Regardless of what I change the date to - or even if I make it =, >=, etc - the same numeric value is displayed.**

If you need anything else, please don't hesitate to ask me.

```
USE [Test_Database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SalesRefCount
AS
BEGIN

--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..DocDOB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DocDOB
DECLARE @NumRecs INT;
-- Count of the number of recommendations


SELECT @NumRecs = COUNT(Recommendation)
FROM [Master_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations]​
WHERE Recommendation = '____Document DOB in pt record' ​
and SalesProcessTime > '2018-10-20'

CREATE TABLE ##RefCount (NumberOfRecs INT); 
INSERT INTO ##RefCount
SELECT @NumRecs

END

EXEC usp_SalesRefCount

SELECT * FROM ##DocDOB
```

Comment: Hey StuckAtWork, at first glance nothing looks wrong on the sp. We need some data from the table [Master_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations]​ if you don't mind

Comment: So you deleted your previous question which provided some insight into your goal. Unfortunately, you did not provide that again and you will incur the same questions. For some reason you fixate on the need to "store" the resultset when, as currently and previously suggested, you can just return the resultset from the procedure directly. So why do you continue to pursue this idea of using some sort of table?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a global temporary table at all?  Why not just return the results from the procedure directly?  eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SalesRefCount
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @NumRecs INT;

  SELECT @NumRecs = COUNT(Recommendation)
  FROM [Master_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations]​
  WHERE Recommendation = '____Document DOB in pt record' ​
  and SalesProcessTime > '2018-10-20'

  SELECT @NumRecs NumRecs 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting data into a global temporary table "##RefCount" and selecting from another one "##DocDOB", so the result will never change.

Anyway, as @DavidBrowne said, you should just return the result directly

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SalesRefCount
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(Recommendation)
  FROM [Master_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations]​
  WHERE Recommendation = '____Document DOB in pt record' ​
  and SalesProcessTime > '2018-10-20'
END
```

Also, another idea, maybe get that date as a parameter, so you don't have to update the stored procedure when you need to select by another date

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SalesRefCount
@selectDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(Recommendation)
  FROM [Master_AGGREGATE].[dbo].[Recommendations]​
  WHERE Recommendation = '____Document DOB in pt record' ​
  and SalesProcessTime > @selectDate
END
```